# Can "your" be omitted from "Majesty"?

Tags: pronouns, titles

We call various people by an associated title, like "Your Majesty", "Your Lordship" etc. I recently stumbled on a fiction case where someone just calls "Eminence". I should maybe highlight that the "dialogue" was like this:

> ”Prosecutor.”
> “Eminence.”

and their underlying meaning was:

> ”Prosecutor, please do what you must.”
> ”Your Eminence, agreed.”

Does the dialogue "shortcut" mode, something which seems formal (I've mostly seen it in high society circles movies), justify the omission of "Your"?

Comment: This has to do with royal etiquette (etc) rather than basic rules of English. In a novel, with fictitious situations, you are free to play with language, but it's recommended you conform largely to the usual rules.

Comment: I'm not clear how to read that dialogue. Are the names, those of the speakers ie. did "Eminence" say "agreed". If it is written as though they were parts in a play - then it ought not to be "Your Eminence" but "His (or her) Eminence".

Comment: @WS2 No, they actually said that. Like, imagine two gentlemen greeting each other: "Mr Charles" "Mr Herrington".

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis In that case there is something wrong with the punctuation. As it stands it doesn't make sense. Who is speaking? And who said "agreed"?

Comment: The second dialogue was a "clarification" by me. The actual one is the first, with only the titles.

Comment: 1) I'm confused. The question is about omitting "your," and you say that you stumbled on an instance in which someone uses "Eminence" without "your"... but then the dialogue you cite uses "Your Eminence." Is that a mistake? 2) If you can, please tell where the quote is from. 3) Yes, many such titles often take a pronoun but can be used without in direct address ("Yes, my lord"/"Yes, lord").

Comment: Wait, I only just now re-read your question enough times to understand it. If the actual dialogue is just two words, there's a lot more being omitted/implied than just possessive pronouns. What we have here is the phenomenon of [communicating volumes simply by addressing someone](https://youtu.be/hoe24aSvLtw).  But your question is still valid—the mode of address would often be "Your eminence." I hope someone can give a better answer than "yeah, that happens sometimes."

Comment: @AndyBonner I'm utterly confused by the whole thing and I'm voting to close - something I rarely do.

Comment: @WS2 I just made some edits that I hope help (and George, I hope you approve). The *actual* dialogue was only one (pregnant) word per person.

Comment: @AndyBonner Still doesn't make sense to me. Central to my confusion is the word "agreed" and the comma prior to it.  Is the sentence being addressed to the Eminence? In other words is the Prosecutor saying "You agreed". Or is it a statement that the Eminence has agreed? In which case it should not be "Your Eminence" but "His" or "Her Eminence". If as you say it is a single word spoken by the Eminence - then it should still be "His Eminence".

Comment: @WS2 Think of "as you wish" instead of "agreed"

Comment: People can say whatever they want if they know each other well. It wouldn't be impossible for the two people to address each other as "Poopy-head" and "Bum-face" but that doesn't mean you should call random monarchs "Poopy-head".

Comment: @WS2 The second block quote is the OP’s paraphrase to try to explain what the actual two-word dialogue conveyed. It’s not idiomatic, but it’s peripheral to the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your Majesty -the title used to speak to or about a king or queen.

**Majesty** can be used instead of 'Your Majesty'.

The programme starts at 6 o'clock, **Majesty**. or The programme starts at 6 o'clock,  Your Majesty.

Your Eminence- a style of reference for high nobility, a title used when talking to or about a cardinal (considered a prince of the church)

'Your' can be omitted from 'Your Eminence' and just 'Eminence' can be used . It is better to use 'Your Eminence' in formal situations or in standard English.

Comment: References would be useful. Particularly, is this based on any particular etiquette rules for a particular country or court?